# giving write permission for a folder only to a specific application

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I am using crontab to run a java code on a linux server and I want to log all messages and exceptions thrown by this code to a file inside /var/log/myapplog/ directory . I have already written the logger class.

But i want to make sure that only this piece of code may create files and write to files inside this directory. Is there a command for this instead of giving write permissions to all (`chmod 777`) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The surest way is to run the program as the only user that may write to this directory. Make a user `myapp`, run `chown myapp /var/log/myapplog` and `chmod 755 /var/log/myapplog` (or `700`), and use `su` in the `crontab` to give the program the proper permissions.

If the program needs different permissions, you might consider splitting the logger out into a different process.